# Newline for caption in Telegram Bot Api Library (.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram-bot

I use Telegram Bot Api Library ([link](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot)) (ver 13.0.1.0) in my Asp.Net project.

I use under code to send image with caption to my channel.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("line1 ");
sb.AppendLine("line2 ");
sb.AppendLine("line3 ");

bot.SendPhotoAsync("@" + channel.Name, fileToSend, sb.ToString(), false, 0);
```

But my problem is that my newline don't show in output

[image]

how can solve this problem and show new line correctly in output?

**[Solved]**

this is the bug of this library and with upgrade to 13.2.0 the problem solved.

Comment: check this if it worked let me know:)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("line1");
sb.Append("line2");
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("line3");
string s = sb.ToString();

Comment: i tested, does not work :(

Comment: @tashakori work for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

using '\n' is possible :

```
string a = "First Line \n Second Line \n Third Line";
```

Answer (score 0):

using "\n" and HttpUtility.UrlEncode(YourText)
this is best way for send text as text or caption if you want to put (hastag #)inside your text or caption

```
    string TextCaption = "First Line \n Second Line \n Third Line \n....";
    bot.SendPhotoAsync("@" + channel.Name, fileToSend, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextCaption ), false, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

not when using .SendTextMessageAsync();

But OP's original solution using StringBuilder() and .appendLine() worked perfectly for me.  Much appreciated...had looked for a similar solution for long time.